# How can I get distinct values of a specific column in arrayList

Tags: java

Assume I have this arrayList :

```
ArrayList<Personne> personnes = new ArrayList<Personne>();
        Personne p1 = new Personne("001590842","51862499", "N5+", "1", "20170201","0");
        Personne p2 = new Personne("001590842","51862499", "X0", "1", "20150529", "1");
        Personne p3 = new Personne("001639055","51862517", "G3", "1", "20170201", "2");
        Personne p4 = new Personne("001639055","51862517", "G3", "1", "20170201", "2");
        Personne p5 = new Personne("001597135","51862517", "G3", "1", "20170201", "2");
        Personne p6 = new Personne("001597135","51862517", "G3", "1", "20170201", "2");
        Personne p7 = new Personne("002804935","00006178","G4","1","19870101","1");
        Personne p8 = new Personne("002804935","00009118","X0","1","19861201","1");
        Personne p9 = new Personne("002804935","00009957","N4+","1","19861229","1");
        Personne p10 = new Personne("002804935","00012970","B3++","1","20100227","1");
        personnes.add(p1);
        personnes.add(p2);
        personnes.add(p3);
        personnes.add(p4);
        personnes.add(p5);
        personnes.add(p6);
        personnes.add(p7);
        personnes.add(p8);
        personnes.add(p9);
        personnes.add(p10);
```

Then I want to get only distinct values of the first column. So the nedeed result should be :

```
001590842
001639055
002804935
```

Note that my Personne class is defined as :

```
public class Personne {

    private String IDT_GCT;
    private String IDC_PSE_PCL;
    private String IDC_CD_NOT;
    private String DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER;
    private String IDT_ETT_PSE;
    private String CD_NOT;

    public Personne(String IDT_GCT, String IDC_PSE_PCL, String IDC_CD_NOT,
                    String DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER, String IDT_ETT_PSE, String CD_NOT) {
        this.IDT_GCT =  IDT_GCT;
        this.IDC_PSE_PCL = IDC_PSE_PCL;
        this.IDC_CD_NOT = IDC_CD_NOT;
        this.DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER = DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER;
        this.IDT_ETT_PSE = IDT_ETT_PSE;
        this.CD_NOT = CD_NOT;
    }

    public String getIDC_CD_NOT() {
        return this.IDC_CD_NOT;
    }

    public String getIDC_PSE_PCL() {
        return this.IDC_PSE_PCL;
    }

    public String getDA_PRM_CTR_ORDER() {
        return this.DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER;
    }

    public String getIDT_ETT_PSE() {
        return this.IDT_ETT_PSE;
    }

    public String getCD_NOT() {
        return this.CD_NOT;
    }

    public String getIDT_GCT() {
        return this.IDT_GCT;
    }

}
```

So I need to get distinct values of IDT_GCT variable.

So I created this function to return this :

```
private static List DistinctValues (ArrayList<Personne> listPersonnes)
{
    List <String> outList = listPersonnes.stream().map(m -> m.get("IDT_GCT")).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return(outList);

}
```

But this returns an error :

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends     R>)
    - The method get(String) is undefined for the type Personne
    - The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments    <String>
```

How can I resolve it please ?

Comment: Override equals and hashcode for the class Personne and use HashSet instead of ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method get(String) is undefined for the type Personne

you should use `getIDT_GCT()` instead

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

private List  DistinctValues(ArrayList listPersonnes) {
        Set uniqueColumnValues = new HashSet <>(); // hash set contains unique values 
        listPersonnes.forEach(item -> uniqueColumnValues.add(item.getIDT_GCT())); // add values to HashSet
        return uniqueColumnValues.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); 
    }